# Convert Json to List<object> with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json

After days to try to convert Json to List of objects, I'm  here.
I have a REST API that return the Json string:

```
{
   GetItemsListResult:"[
      {
         "code":"VOL00056",
         "clsID":223108653,
         "type":2,
         "status":1,
         "free":0.0,
         "total":671088640.0,
         "perc":99,
         "descr":"no mailing",
         "dt":20160926,
         "tm":112456,
         "full":1
      },
      {
         "code":"VOL00055",
         "clsID":111760419,
         "type":2,
         "status":1,
         "free":0.0,
         "total":671088640.0,
         "perc":99,
         "descr":"Email",
         "dt":20160817,
         "tm":222411,
         "full":1
      }
   ]"
}
```

I know that this string comes from a DataTable:

```
String JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
```

I created two class: one that describe the object model and another that get the collection. But when trying to

```
VolumeCollection volumes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VolumeCollection>(listVolumes);
```

I obtain 
    Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Volume].

What is wrong?

Volume Class:

```
public class Volume
    {
        public String code  { get; set; }
        public Int32 classId  { get; set; }
        public Byte volumeType  { get; set; }
        public Byte status  { get; set; }
        public float freeSpace  { get; set; }
        public float totalSpace { get; set; }
        public Int16 fillPercentage { get; set; }
        public String classDescription { get; set; }
        public Int32 closeDate { get; set; }
        public Int32 closeTime { get; set; }
        public Boolean isFull { get; set; }
}
```

The json string received is:
"\"
[{\\"FreeSpace\\":0.0,\\"TotalSpace\\":671088640.0,\\"FillPercentage\\":99,\\"ClassDescription\\":\\"Email esterne\\",\\"CloseDate\\":20161001,\\"CloseTime\\":212512,\\"IsFull\\":true,\\"VolumeType\\":2,\\"ClassId\\":111760419,\\"Code\\":\\"VOL00057\\",\\"Status\\":1},
{\\"FreeSpace\\":0.0,\\"TotalSpace\\":671088640.0,\\"FillPercentage\\":99,\\"ClassDescription\\":\\"Corrispondenza no mailing\\",\\"CloseDate\\":20160926,\\"CloseTime\\":112456,\\"IsFull\\":true,\\"VolumeType\\":2,\\"ClassId\\":223108653,\\"Code\\":\\"VOL00056\\",\\"Status\\":1}
]\""

It seems to be a not valid json...

Comment: Can you share your `VolumeCollection` class?

Comment: public class VolumeCollection
        {
            public List<Volume> GetItemsListResult { get; set; }
        }

Comment: you have invalid json string

Comment: Could you share the `Volume` class too? Preferably add it to your question. As well as the `VolumeCollection` class.

Comment: Your JSON string is invalid. That's why it can't deserialize. Can you post the controller generating that JSON? Something is wrong with that part.

Answer (score 3):

Given that your `json` is not valid and given that the following is:

```
{
    "GetItemsListResult": [{
        "code": "VOL00056",
        "clsID": 223108653,
        "type": 2,
        "status": 1,
        "free": 0.0,
        "total": 671088640.0,
        "perc": 99,
        "descr": "no mailing",
        "dt": 20160926,
        "tm": 112456,
        "full": 1
    }, {
        "code": "VOL00055",
        "clsID": 111760419,
        "type": 2,
        "status": 1,
        "free": 0.0,
        "total": 671088640.0,
        "perc": 99,
        "descr": "Email",
        "dt": 20160817,
        "tm": 222411,
        "full": 1
    }]
}
```

using the following classes that I generated, this works:

```
    public class GetItemsListResult
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public int clsID { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public double free { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public int perc { get; set; }
        public string descr { get; set; }
        public int dt { get; set; }
        public int tm { get; set; }
        public int full { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<GetItemsListResult> GetItemsListResult { get; set; }
    }
```

`var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`

N.B: this site generated the classes from the `JSON`: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Ok, given that the json comes from a DataTable, can I change it? Can I rename GetItemsListResult with a name significative?

Comment: Not sure I follow you, are you saying that you don't control how the json is created?

Comment: More or less... I can "convice" who prepare the json :-) The data comes from a database table. How can I change the preparation of data?

Comment: Instead of just using a DataTable in the first place, create objects from each row of the table, then serialize that into `json` instead, it's much more maintainable.

Comment: Ok, instead of a DataTable, loop with a DataReader and create the list of object. Right?

Comment: Yeah, that'll do the trick. Or, still load into a DataTable then read each row. DataReader will be faster though.

Comment: No worries, it all comes down to how you want to implement it, either way will work.

Comment: After changed the code to convert datatable to a list of object and then serialize to json, I obtain same result. I figured out who put the GetItemsListResult string. The API Rest comes from WCF service 

[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "itemslist/{id}")]
        string GetItemsList(string id);

How can avoid to put it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetItemsListResult` is a string, not an array.  Notice the double quotes:

```
GetItemsListResult: "[
```

So, ideally you want to fix your json to be a real array.

If you don't have control over the json, then as a poor alternative you could recursively parse the strings to extract the array.

Answer (score 1):

1. you have invalid json string:

1.1 valid json like this:

```
{
"GetItemsListResult":[
{"code":"VOL00056","clsID":223108653,"type":2,"status":1,"free":0.0,"total":671088640.0,"perc":99,"descr":"no mailing","dt":20160926,"tm":112456,"full":1},
{"code":"VOL00055","clsID":111760419,"type":2,"status":1,"free":0.0,"total":671088640.0,"perc":99,"descr":"Email","dt":20160817,"tm":222411,"full":1}
]
}
```

2. With http://json2csharp.com/ build data model

2.1 like this:

```
public class GetItemsListResult
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int clsID { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public double free { get; set; }
    public double total { get; set; }
    public int perc { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public int tm { get; set; }
    public int full { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<GetItemsListResult> GetItemsListResult { get; set; }
}
```

3. with http://www.newtonsoft.com/json help parse you json

3.1 like this:

```
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```