# C# Reading Data from JSON Textfile using streamreader and Deserializing it into respective lists of objects

Tags: c#

I am relatively new to c# programming. I need help for these problems that i have been facing in assignment.

```
 {

     "Non_Portable": [{
             "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Playstation 4",
             "ResourceId": 1,
             "RentalPrice": 200,
             "DeliveryMode": "Hand Carry",
             "quantityOfCables": 2,
             "TypeOfCable": "Micro USB for controller and HDMI for display",
             "Accessories": "2 wireless Dualshock 4 controllers"
         }, {
             "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Xbox One",
             "ResourceId": 2,
             "RentalPrice": 200,
             "DeliveryMode": " Hand Carry",
             "quantityOfCables": 2,
             "TypeOfCable": " Micro USB cable for controller and HDMI cable for display",
             "Accessories": "batteries for controller"
         }, {
             "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Playstation 3",
             "ResourceId": 3,
             "RentalPrice": 120,
             "DeliveryMode": "delivery via deliveryman",
             "quantityOfCables": 1,
             "TypeOfCable": "HDMI cable for display",
             "Accessories": "Wireless dualshock 3 controller for Playstation 3"
         }

     ],


     "Portable": [{
         "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Nintendo 3DS",
         "ResourceId": 4,
         "RentalPrice": 50,
         "DeliveryMode": "Hand carry",
         "sizeOfScreen": "Top: 4.88 Bottom: 4.18",
         "quantityOfCartridges": 1,
         "CartridgeName": "Super Mario",
         "touchScreenFunction": true
     }, {
         "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Sony Playstation Vita",
         "ResourceId": 5,
         "RentalPrice": 70,
         "DeliveryMode": "Self Pick Up",
         "sizeOfScreen": "5 inches",
         "quantityOfCartridges": 2,
         "CartridgeName": "Powerpuff Girls and GTA ",
         "touchScreenFunction": true
     }, {
         "NameOfGamingEquipments": "Nintendo 3DS XL",
         "ResourceId": 6,
         "RentalPrice": 40,
         "DeliveryMode": "Self Pick Up",
         "sizeOfScreen": "Top: 4.88 bottom: 4.18 ",
         "quantityOfCartridges": 1,
         "CartridgeName": "Ridge Racer",
         "touchScreenFunction": true
     }]
 }
```

The above is my JSON File. The assignment requires me to load data from text file hence I am using streamreader to read the data from json.

```
public class Resource {
 public static List < UserAccount > UserAccounts {
   get;
   set;
  } //container     for useraccounts
 public List < Non_Portable > Non_PortableEquip {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public List < Portable > PortableEquip {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public List < Booking > Bookings {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public List < BookingDetail > BookingDetails {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public abstract class GamingEquipment {
  public string NameOfGamingEquipments

  {
   get;
   set;
  }


  public int ResourceId

  {
   get;
   set;
  }



  public double RentalPrice {
   get;
   set;
  }


  public string DeliveryMode

  {
   get;
   set;
  }


 }

 public class Non_Portable: GamingEquipment {


  public int quantityOfCables

  {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public string TypeOfCable

  {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public string Accessories

  {
   get;
   set;
  }



 }



 public class Portable: GamingEquipment {
  public string sizeOfScreen

  {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public double quantityOfCartridges

  {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public string CartridgeName

  {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public bool touchScreenFunction

  {
   get;
   set;
  }


 }

 public class UserAccount {
  private string userName;
  private string passWord;
  private string name;
  private string email;
  private int cardNum;
  private DateTime expiryDate;
  private string paymentType;
  private string address;
  public string Username {
   set {
    userName = value;
   }

   get {
    return userName;
   }
  }

  public string Password {
   set {
    passWord = value;
   }

   get {
    return passWord;
   }
  }


  public string Name {
   set {
    name = value;
   }

   get {
    return name;
   }
  }


  public string Email {
   set {
    email = value;
   }
   get {
    return email;
   }
  }


  public int CardNum {
   set {
    cardNum = value;
   }
   get {
    return cardNum;
   }
  }

  public DateTime ExpiryDate {
   set {
    expiryDate = value;
   }
   get {
    return expiryDate;
   }
  }


  public string PaymentType {
   set {
    paymentType = value;
   }
   get {
    return paymentType;
   }
  }


  public string Address {
   set {
    address = value;
   }
   get {
    return address;
   }
  }
 }
```

Now then I have read the `json` data from the file, How do I deserialize json data and have them collected to their respective lists ? I am working in windows form application. Thanks for everyone's help and advice in advance.

Reading json data from file

```
using(StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@ "Data.JSON")) {}
```

Comment: I am very lost, i hope you can give me some advice on how to approach the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: what are the structures of UserAccount,Non_Portable,Portable etc..?

Comment: Try using the json.net library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Json to List<object> with .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853784/convert-json-to-listobject-with-net)

Comment: @DarkKnight, I have updated it. The problem is that i need to use inheritance in c# classes which i am afraid tht once i organize list<Non Portable> nonportables and list<Portable> portables and group under rootobject, it will affect Because my assignment requires me to use inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416621/3796048) JSON.Net using Package Manager and then you can create the classes for your JSON like this

```
public class NonPortable
{
    [JsonProperty("NameOfGamingEquipments")]
    public string NameOfGamingEquipments { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ResourceId")]
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("RentalPrice")]
    public int RentalPrice { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("DeliveryMode")]
    public string DeliveryMode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("quantityOfCables")]
    public int quantityOfCables { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TypeOfCable")]
    public string TypeOfCable { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Accessories")]
    public string Accessories { get; set; }
}

public class Portable
{
    [JsonProperty("NameOfGamingEquipments")]
    public string NameOfGamingEquipments { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ResourceId")]
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("RentalPrice")]
    public int RentalPrice { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("DeliveryMode")]
    public string DeliveryMode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sizeOfScreen")]
    public string sizeOfScreen { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("quantityOfCartridges")]
    public int quantityOfCartridges { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CartridgeName")]
    public string CartridgeName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("touchScreenFunction")]
    public bool touchScreenFunction { get; set; }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("Non_Portable")]
    public IList<NonPortable> Non_Portable { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Portable")]
    public IList<Portable> Portable { get; set; }
}
```

and then desearlize it like this

```
string jsonstr = File.ReadAllText("YourJsonFile");
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonstr);
```

You will get all your data like this

```
foreach(NonPortable np in ser.Non_Portable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(np.Accessories);
    Console.WriteLine(np.DeliveryMode);
    Console.WriteLine(np.NameOfGamingEquipments);
    Console.WriteLine(np.quantityOfCables);
    Console.WriteLine(np.RentalPrice);
    Console.WriteLine(np.ResourceId);
    Console.WriteLine(np.TypeOfCable);
}
```

**Edit**

*I have to use inheritance in my assignment that non portable class and portable class will inherit properties from the base class gaming equipments*
Your classes would look like this

```
public abstract class GamingEquipment
{
    public string NameOfGamingEquipments { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public double RentalPrice { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryMode { get; set; }
}
public class NonPortable : GamingEquipment
{
    public int quantityOfCables { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfCable { get; set; }
    public string Accessories { get; set; }
}

public class Portable : GamingEquipment
{
    public string sizeOfScreen { get; set; }
    public int quantityOfCartridges { get; set; }
    public string CartridgeName { get; set; }
    public bool touchScreenFunction { get; set; }
}
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<NonPortable> Non_Portable { get; set; }
    public List<Portable> Portable { get; set; }
}
```

and still the Deserialization and other things will be same with no changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I consider using these, but I have to use inheritance in my assignment that non portable class and portable class will inherit properties from the base class gaming equipments.

Comment: public abstract class GamingEquipment
    {
        public string NameOfGamingEquipments

        { get; set; }


        public int ResourceId

        { get; set; }



        public double RentalPrice
        {
            get; set;
        }


        public string DeliveryMode

        { get; set; }


    }

    public class Non_Portable : GamingEquipment
    {
       
        

    }



    public class Portable : GamingEquipment
    {
    }

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer / solution @SofiaWong

Comment: Could not find file 'C:\Application Development Project\APPD_Assignment\APPD_Assignment\bin\Debug\Data.JSON'.

Comment: string jsonstr = File.ReadAllText("Data.JSON"); This is my code but i have a error. Could not find file 'C:\Application Development Project\APPD_Assignment\APPD_Assignment\bin\Debug\Data.JSON'.  I have this error.

Comment: Your program is expecting the Data.JSON file to be in the directory: C:\Application Development Project\APPD_Assignment\APPD_Assignment\bin\Debug. Either add it there, or add it to your solution so that it can be added there at run time for you.